# Unable to run Appium protractor tests on iOS

Tags: ios, protractor, appium

I successfully set up Appium on Mac Yosemite 10.10.5 version. I have both Xcode 7.2.1 and xcode 6.1.1. I installed ideviceInstaller as well.

I connected my iOS device on the Mac and started the appium server. When trying to run the protractor test, I am getting the following error.

Phones used:
Iphone 6 plus: Version: 9.3.1
iPhone 5c: Version 9.2.1
Appium: 1.5.2

Logs:

```
BaseDriver] The following capabilities were provided, but are not recognized by appium: appium-version, count.
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: 47c8905c-afc5-4786-a218-01e6425f3aea
[debug] [iOS] Not auto-detecting udid.
[debug] [iOS] Creating iDevice object with udid 58ae05dd744e1e1329bc4ffb4c8599bddd6f0378

[debug] [iOS] Checking for presence of SafariLauncher at '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-ios-driver/build/SafariLauncher/SafariLauncher.app'

[debug] [iOS] SafariLauncher does not exist

[debug] [iOS] SafariLauncher not found, building...
[iOS] Cleaning SafariLauncher

[debug] [iOS] Cleaning SafariLauncher for iphoneos8.1

[iOS] Finished cleaning SafariLauncher

[iOS] Updating config for Safari Launcher

[iOS] Building SafariLauncher
[debug] [iOS] Building SafariLauncher for iphoneos8.1

[iOS] Error: Command 'xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos8.1 -xcconfig /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-ios-driver/node_modules/safari-launcher/build.xcconfig' exited with code 65
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (lib/teen_process.js:65:19)
    at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:850:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:323:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:7)
    at Pipe._onclose (net.js:475:12)
 { [Error: Command 'xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos8.1 -xcconfig /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-ios-driver/node_modules/safari-launcher/build.xcconfig' exited with code 65]
  stdout: 'Build settings from command line:\n    SDKROOT = iphoneos8.1\n\nBuild settings from configuration file \'/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-ios-driver/node_modules/safari-launcher/build.xcconfig\':\n    BUNDLE_ID = com.bytearc.SafariLauncher\n    IDENTITY_CODE = \n    IDENTITY_NAME = iPhone Developer\n\n=== BUILD TARGET SafariLauncher OF PROJECT SafariLauncher WITH THE DEFAULT CONFIGURATION (Release) ===\n\nCheck dependencies\nCode Sign error: No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the team ID “(null)” were found.\nCodeSign error: code signing is required for product type \'Application\' in SDK \'iOS 8.1\'\n\n',
  stderr: '** BUILD FAILED **\n\n\nThe following build commands failed:\n\tCheck dependencies\n(1 failure)\n',
  code: 65 }

[iOS] Error: Command 'xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos8.1 -xcconfig /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-ios-driver/node_modules/safari-launcher/build.xcconfig' exited with code 65
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (lib/teen_process.js:65:19)
    at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:850:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:323:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:7)
    at Pipe._onclose (net.js:475:12)
 { [Error: Command 'xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos8.1 -xcconfig /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-ios-driver/node_modules/safari-launcher/build.xcconfig' exited with code 65]
  stdout: 'Build settings from command line:\n    SDKROOT = iphoneos8.1\n\nBuild settings from configuration file \'/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-ios-driver/node_modules/safari-launcher/build.xcconfig\':\n    BUNDLE_ID = com.bytearc.SafariLauncher\n    IDENTITY_CODE = \n    IDENTITY_NAME = iPhone Developer\n\n=== BUILD TARGET SafariLauncher OF PROJECT SafariLauncher WITH THE DEFAULT CONFIGURATION (Release) ===\n\nCheck dependencies\nCode Sign error: No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the team ID “(null)” were found.\nCodeSign error: code signing is required for product type \'Application\' in SDK \'iOS 8.1\'\n\n',
  stderr: '** BUILD FAILED **\n\n\nThe following build commands failed:\n\tCheck dependencies\n(1 failure)\n',
  code: 65 }
[iOS] Bad app: '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-ios-driver/build/SafariLauncher/SafariLauncher.app'. App paths need to be absolute, or relative to the appium server install dir, or a URL to compressed file, or a special app name.

[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 2678 ms - 410 

[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Bad app: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-ios-driver/build/SafariLauncher/SafariLauncher.app. App paths need to be absolute, or relative to the appium server install dir, or a URL to compressed file, or a special app name.
    at IosDriver.configureApp$ (lib/driver.js:250:13)
    at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as throw] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
    at run (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.promise.js:104:47)
    at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.promise.js:115:28
    at flush (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/$.microtask.js:19:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Protractor logs:

[14:57:11] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4723/wd/hub
[14:57:11] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/error.js:27
    super(opt_error);
    ^
WebDriverError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Bad app: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-ios-driver/build/SafariLauncher/SafariLauncher.app. App paths need to be absolute, or relative to the appium server install dir, or a URL to compressed file, or a special app name.
    at WebDriverError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/error.js:27:5)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/error.js:580:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:64:13
    at Promise.invokeCallback_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1329:14)
    at TaskQueue.execute_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2790:14)
    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pro[14:57:13] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Protractor Appium Conf file

capabilities: {
     browserName: 'safari',
     'appium-version': '1.5.2',
     platformName: 'iOS',
     platformVersion: '9.3.1',
     deviceName: 'iPhone 6+',
    udid: '********************'

   },

specs: [
    '../appiumTests/AppiumSmokeTest.js'
  ],
```

Comment: I think this is the issue I have. I do not have Safari launcher configured. Do I need to have apple dev account? I think it is paid, isn't it https://azevedorafaela.wordpress.com/tag/how-install-safari-launcher-to-run-appium-framework/

Comment: *Bad app: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-ios-driver/build/SafariLauncher/SafariLauncher.app. App paths need to be absolute, or relative to the appium server install dir, or a URL to compressed file, or a special app name.* this is the issue.

Comment: I am not trying to run the apk. Trying to  run the protractor tests .. I googled that error and all the responses were to set the apk path and in my case it is just a file. Please advise